# Threads and ARM processor utilization

Tags: android, android-ndk, pthreads

Good day!
I port me linux application based on posix threads to android. 
I need thread to read data from my USB device every 20 ms. 
But when I use it my cortex-a15 (exynos 5410) clock goes from 250 Mhz to 1.8Ghz.
Is there some way to use periodic work in android NDK, 
or how can I reduce cpu utilization from pthreads?
Thanx in advance
Bye

```
void dynamics_thread::run()
{
        _done = false;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((__int64_t *)&init_time);  // Get current count
        do
        {
                //YieldCurrentThread();
                if (raschet_flag)
                {
                        __int64_t freq;
                        QueryPerformanceCounter((__int64_t *)&current_time);  // Get current count
                        QueryPerformanceFrequency((__int64_t *)&freq); // Get processor freq
                        current_time-=init_time;
                        deltaTime = (float)((float)(current_time - gLastTime)/(float)freq);
                        if (deltaTime>=0.02f)
                        {
                        gTime = (float)((float)(current_time)/(float)freq);
                        //osg::notify(osg::WARN)<<"begin "<<gTime<<std::endl;
                        gLastTime = current_time;
                        // do some work  
                        }

                }
                microSleep(20000);
        }
        while( !_done );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a thread busy waiting or polling?  Where does it spend it's time in between the 20ms access?  if not in a blocking kernel call, that is your problem.  While using threads may involve some degree of overhead from context switching, the real cost is going to be in *what you do with the thread* rather than the mere fact that you have one.

Comment: Should I use sleep fuction to block thread from execution?

Comment: That would be better than nothing; best would be if you are waiting in kernel context on some precise trigger.  Also consider if you can batch/buffer things so that you move more data less often.

Comment: Is there some example how can I make it?

Comment: Post the current code of where it spends this time.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I use library cross platform library OpenThreads

Comment: my code is http://pastebin.com/y0aRMrMB. I added sleep function and it solves problem. But maybe you tell me how to make it in kernel context  with precise trigger?

Comment: Post the relevant code *in* your question

Comment: What is the point of even doing this?  Where is the data produced by this thread consumed?  Couldn't you just measure the time in whatever is setting / unsetting the flag?

Comment: Under comment //do some work I simply calculate my math. All data goes to another thread under locked mutex.